# Error while creating array of struct and initializing elements in it

Tags: go

i'm trying to create array with two elements in it  but i got an error

```
 type TODO struct {
    Number             int
    Task               string
}

func main() {
    var todoArr [2]TODO

    fE := &TODO{Number: 10, Task: "Task1"}
    sE := &TODO{Number: 11, Task: "Task2"}
    todoArr[0] = fE
    todoArr[1] = sE
}
```

> cannot use fE (type *TODO) as Type TODO in assignment

i don't know why 
also i want to know if there is a short form to declare and initialize array/slice in golang like this

```
[]TODO{&TODO{Number: 10, Task: "Task1"}, &TODO{Number: 11, Task: "Task2"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to declare an array of pointer to TODO:

```
var todoArr [2]*TODO

fE := &TODO{Number: 10, Task: "Task1"}
sE := &TODO{Number: 11, Task: "Task2"}
todoArr[0] = fE
todoArr[1] = sE
```

or change the code to put TODO values in the array:

```
var todoArr [2]TODO

fE := TODO{Number: 10, Task: "Task1"}
sE := TODO{Number: 11, Task: "Task2"}
todoArr[0] = fE
todoArr[1] = sE
```

You  can declare a slice using literal syntax as

```
[]*TODO{&TODO{Number: 10, Task: "Task1"}, &TODO{Number: 11, Task: "Task2"}}
```

or

```
[]TODO{TODO{Number: 10, Task: "Task1"}, TODO{Number: 11, Task: "Task2"}}
```

depending on your choice of using pointers or not.